# Perl - How to access and array element that's held within another array

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

Heylo again,

I've been trying to make my program somewhat easier to maintain. I have an array which I declare:

```
my @pizza = ($p1 = "Pizza One", $p2 = "Pizza Two" );
```

I then go ahead and put this @Pizza array in another array, like so:

```
my @food = (\@pizza);
```

When I attempt to access either $p1 or $p2 via the @food property I get a value returned like "Array{0x8001}" which appears to be a memory reference. What i tried was this:

```
$test = ${$food[$pizza[$p1]]};
```

What is the corret way to access this? I am looking to NOT use indexes in order to ease program readability. could you guys point me in the right direction?

Regards,

---

This is what I am trying to do:

I have several databases (for talks sake this is an example)

Database One
Table One (D1T1) | Column One | Column Two | Column Three | Column Four
Table Two (D1T2) | Column One | Column Two | Column Three

Database Two
Table One   (D2T1) | Column One | Column Two| Column Three
Table Two   (D2T2) | Column One | Column Two| Column Three
Table Three (D2T2) | Column One | Column Two| Column Three

Between these two databases there is information that is relative to particular records right across them both. What I am trying to do is create an array (each array will represent a database) and insert variables (each variable will represent a table.field.  within the datasource) Once I have done this I am creating an array to hold all teh arrays (The ones that represent the db's) as this array will represent a single entry right across the two databases which I can then act on. Example:

@D1 = ( t1.col1, t1.col4, t2.col1 );
@D2 = ( t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col2, t3.col3);

@rec = ( \@D1, \@D2 );

If I want to know what was held in Database 2 -> Table 2 -> Column 4 what would the statement be? Should I be using hashes instead? I do have a requirement for this two dimensional array/hash.

Any help is much appreciated.

MC

Comment: is there any reason you're using an array here instead of a hash?
What you're doing in the first line is creating an array: @pizza = ("Pizza One", "Pizza Two") and two variables $p1 = "Pizza One", $p2 = "Pizza Two".  This is more or less where I lose you.
Are you trying to find the index of @pizza that has the value $p1?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you stopped and described the data structure you are trying to build and how you want to access it.  Something like: I want a list of foods broken down by categories such as pizza, and I want those categories to hold individual recipes accessible by recipe name (such as "Hawaiian Pizza").  Once we know what you are doing with the data we will be able to help you.

Comment: Even if you don't want to explain your problem from first principles and ask for suggested solutions, at least explain what you think you're doing with the code you've posted.  The my @pizza = ($p1 = "Pizza One", $p2 = "Pizza Two" ) just looks weird and so since it's not obvious what you're trying to do it's hard to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have added some more information which I hope answers your questions. I really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: I think I have confused myself with the limitations of arrays and instead should be focusing on hashes! Still would love some advice on how I should go about achieving this!

Comment: Read this: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Comment: $p1 eq $food[0][0]; $p2 eq $food[0][1];

Answer (score 10):

Not knowing what you're trying to accomplish, what data you're modeling, all I can help you with is the syntax confusion.  There's confusion here on several points.

```
# You wrote
my @pizza = ($p1 = "Pizza One", $p2 = "Pizza Two" );
```

That does not do what you mean.  It makes the array `("Pizza One", "Pizza Two")` but it also sets `$p1` to be `Pizza One` and `$p2` to be `Pizza Two`.  I think you're trying to assign `Pizza One` to the key `p1`.  I think you want to use a hash/associated array:

```
# Try a hash
my %pizzas = (p1 => "Pizza One", p2 => "Pizza Two");
```

Now `$pizzas{p1}` is `Pizza One`.  Alternatively, just make a list:

```
# An array
my @pizzas = ("Pizza One", "Pizza Two");
```

And then `$pizzas[0]` is `Pizza One`.  Moving on...

```
# You wrote
my @food = (\@pizza);
```

You're trying to make another list refer to `@pizza`.  The above makes `$food[0]` reference to `@pizza` which is not what you meant.  References in Perl are scalars and have different syntax.

```
# What you probably meant
my $food = \@pizza;
```

Now `$food->[0]` is `Pizza One` and `$food->[0]` is `Pizza Two`.

```
# You wrote
$test = ${$food[$pizza[$p1]]};
```

Smacks of just adding more braces until you got output.  I'd recommend reading the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).  Oh, and turn on warnings.  Don't turn them off until they all go away and don't turn them off because there's too many of them.  Really.  Really really.

**Update**

*"I want to know what was held in Database 2 -> Table 2 -> Column 4 what would the statement be?"*

Don't use numbers.  Name them, because I'm sure they have names.  So yes, you want hashes.  So let's say Database Foo -> Table Bar -> Column Baz.  You'd access that like...

```
$values = $databases->{Foo}{Bar}{Baz};
```

or long hand

```
$tables  = $databases->{Foo};
$columns = $tables->{Bar};
$values  = $columns->{Baz};
```

Where `$values` can be an array ref of all the values of Foo.Bar.Baz, or another hash keyed by the primary key of Foo.Bar.  Which makes more sense depends on what you're doing to do with the data.

I'll leave it to you to adapt Chaz's answer to generate hashes instead of arrays.

Of course, I must ask why dump the whole of both databases out into a big in-memory structure and then work on it?  If you have databases, query them.  It'll be faster and more flexible.

We're back to that most basic of questions; what is it you're REALLY trying to do?

Comment: I think he means he doesn't want a lot of magic numbers sprinkled through his code (like $object[1]), for which the solution is either a hashref instead of an arrayref, or "use constant" or "use enum" to declare constants for your field indexes.

Comment: That is exactly is cjm. The keys I will access need to represent the data they hold. I have edited the original post to clarify what it is I am trying to do.

I think hash references are the way to go, I'm googling up two dimensional hashes to see if I get anywhere. I really appreciate you help.

Comment: Ahh, I misparsed it as "I am NOT looking to use indexes..."

Comment: Hi Schwern, thanks for the answer.

What I am trying to do is collect (relative) information across a wide range of databases, and once I've collected that information I will begin performing checks on this information that will trigger an activity based on that information. I will sometimes need to perform checks of D1T2C1 (Database One, Table Two, column One) to make sure the value of its relative record D2T1C1 (Database Two, Table One, Column One) has a particular value.

Please note that I don't hold the entire db in memory, I flush the memory on each record iteration and recheck.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described is sounds like you need something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @dbs;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^Database/) {
        push @dbs, [];
        next;
    }
    my @table = split /\s*\|\s*/;
    push @{$dbs[-1]}, [ @table[1 .. $#table] ];
}

print "datbase 1, table 2, column 1: $dbs[0][1][0]\n";

for my $db (0 .. $#dbs) {
    for my $table (0 .. $#{$dbs[$db]}) {
        for my $col (0 .. $#{$dbs[$db][$table]}) {
            print "($db,  $table, $col) is $dbs[$db][$table][$col]\n";
        }
    }
}


__DATA__
Database One
Table One (D1T1) | D1T1C1 | D1T1C2 | D1T1C3 | D1T1C4
Table Two (D1T2) | D1T2C1 | D1T2C2 | D1T2C3

Database Two
Table One (D2T1)   | D2T1C1 | D2T1C2 | D2T1C3
Table Two (D2T2)   | D2T2C1 | D2T2C2 | D2T2C3
Table Three (D2T2) | D2T3C1 | D2T3C2 | D2T3C3
```